# Disable Client-side caching in .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, console, .net-core, browser-cache

I'm trying to run some Azure batch jobs, and I'll get to the end when I get a 403 Forbidden from the Azure service.  Upon googling, I discovered [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maheshk/2016/12/20/azure-batch-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request/) which implies the issue is related to client-side caching of credentials, and offers a solution by modifying the config file like so:

```
<system.net>
    <requestCaching defaultPolicyLevel="NoCacheNoStore"/>
```

Problem is, this is a .NET Core console application, and such a config file does not exist.

How can I disable the request caching for my .NET Core console project comparably to the above solution for .NET Framework 4.x?

Comment: .NET Core uses WinHTTP HTTP stack implementation on Windows by default. And WinHTTP doesn't have a HTTP caching mechanism. See [How do I utilize HTTP caching with WinHttpHandler and HttpClient?](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25854) issue on .NET Core Github. Probably you need to debug your application to find out which request causing the issue and why. You can use debugging proxy like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). In order to bypass intermediate proxy caches you can try to add `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0` HTTP header to the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Leonid mentioned, by default the .NET Core components do not have an Http Cache, so nothing needs to be done here.

As it turns out, the problem I was experiencing was a known bug to the Azure Batch development team for .NET Core 2.1, and they expect to have a fix out soon.

Comment: Having similar problems in .NET Core 3.0; do you know if this problem has been resolved yet?

Comment: updated to 3.1, just in case, but also having the same issue.

Comment: I believed I just kept the project at 2.0 and it worked, haven't visited it since then...